How can I render a form with an array of zeros using react-hook-form?
I have a basic form where the code for it is using react-hook-form and looks like:
import "./styles.css";
import { useForm, useFieldArray, Control, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import { useState } from 'react';

const defaultValues = {
  "foo": [
    {
      "bar": [0, 0, 0]
    },
    {
      "bar": [4, 5, 6]
    }
  ]
}


const FooComponent = ({fooIndex, control}) => {
  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: `foo.${fooIndex}.bar`,
    keyName: 'id'
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Foo</h1>
      {fields.map((field, index) => (
        <Controller
          key={field.id}
          name={`foo.${fooIndex}.bar.${index}`}
          control={control}
          defaultValue={String(field.value)} // Convert to string
          render={({field}) => (
            <input {...field} value={String(field.value)} /> // Ensure the value is a string
          )}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
};


export default function App() {
  const { control, handleSubmit, getValues } = useForm({
    defaultValues
  });
  const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState(null);

  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: 'foo',
    keyName: 'id'
  });

  const onSubmit = async () => {

  };

  const handlePrintForm = () => {
    setFormValue(getValues())
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <h1>Form value:</h1>
        <p>{JSON.stringify(formValue, null, 2)}</p>
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        {fields.map((field, index) => (
          <div key={field.id}>
            <FooComponent fooIndex={index} control={control}/>
          </div>
        ))}
        <button onClick={(()=>append({'bar': [1, 2, 3]}))}>Add Foo</button>
      </form>
      <button onClick={handlePrintForm}>Print form</button>
    </div>
  );
}

When there is an array with zero-values in it, the form displays the number of zeros in the array, fewer than it should. For instance, with an array of all zeros nothing gets shown:

Whereas an array with [0, 1, 2]:

How can I fix this?
codesandbox link

The solution iniubong Obonguko has provided is more or less correct, as field array must be an array of objects for useFieldArray to function properly.
You can verify this in their official docs by checking the type of fields and parameter types for all array-related functions (see useFieldArray > Return > fields):

A couple of minor corrections to the above solution though:

there's no need to remove string coercion you can keep using String(field.value).
append({ bar: [1, 2, 3] }) should be updated to append({ bar: [{ field: 1 }, { field: 2 }, { field: 3 }] }) (you can use whatever name instead of field).
you can remove keyName as it will be removed in the next major version (see useFieldArray > Props > keyName).

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/happy-bouman-8m8sjm?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A1%2C1-81%2C1

I made the following change to the code

Using an array of objects instead of just primitives.
Removing the String coercion and replacing JSON.stringify with the toString() method.

This should work now.
import "./styles.css";
import { useForm, useFieldArray, Control, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { useState } from "react";

const defaultValues = {
  foo: [
    {
      bar: [{ data: 0 }, { data: 0 }, { data: 0 }],
    },
    {
      bar: [{ data: 4 }, { data: 5 }, { data: 6 }],
    },
  ],
};

const FooComponent = ({ fooIndex, control }) => {
  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: `foo.${fooIndex}.bar`,
    keyName: "id",
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Foo</h1>
      {fields.map((field, index) => (
        <Controller
          key={field.id}
          name={`foo.${fooIndex}.bar.${index}.data`}
          control={control}
          defaultValue={field.data}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <input {...field} value={field.value.toString()} /> // Ensure the value is a string
          )}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const { control, handleSubmit, getValues } = useForm({
    defaultValues,
    shouldUnregister: false,
  });
  const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState(null);

  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "foo",
    keyName: "id",
  });

  const onSubmit = async () => {};

  const handlePrintForm = () => {
    setFormValue(getValues());
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <h1>Form value:</h1>
        <p>{JSON.stringify(formValue, null, 2)}</p>
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        {fields.map((field, index) => (
          <div key={field.id}>
            <FooComponent fooIndex={index} control={control} />
          </div>
        ))}
        <button onClick={() => append({ bar: [1, 2, 3] })}>Add Foo</button>
      </form>
      <button onClick={handlePrintForm}>Print form</button>
    </div>
  );
}


Thanks for the answer, I was hoping not to have to turn the numbers into objects as the form state is actually coming from an API which will return the field as an array of numbers. I guess if nothing works, I can apply a step which converts number arrays into object arrays.

Does the API return strictly number values? If yes, then instead of converting to an array of objects, you can simply convert the data to an array of strings instead. Should work just fine.

You will need to convert the data into an array of objects, as that's what the library expects to work properly. Converting to an array of strings would not work either. See my answer for more details.
